# Random number generation in R with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have this problem below to address. Your inputs/pointers are very much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

I have a data.table called Defect. And the first column is Length

```
Defect Table : 

Length

6355
6236
1345 
3123
```

I want to add two more columns called DefectStarts and DefectEnds. I would like to use **random** function to determine where the defect starts and where it ends.

Basic criteria is as follows:

```
 DefectStarts and DefectEnds <= Length

 DefectEnds > DefectStarts

 DefectEnds - DefectStarts <= Length
```

Final data should something like this(values could be different as long as it satisfies above conditions)

```
 Defect table:

Length     DefectStarts     DefectEnds

6355         1234             4356

6236         2000             4567

1345         500               689

3123         342               3120
```

Comment: what is meant by random function?

Comment: I am sorry, my idea is to use a function in R which generates random values satisfying these criteria. I am not sure what is that function called in R..

Comment: A random function in R could be `runif(N)`, N stands the number of pseudo random number you wish to have.

Comment: Thanks amonk! But how to incorporate these conditions in the runif function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runif(n, min, max)` generates `n` random numbers with a range from `min` to `max`. The latter two arguments can be vectors.

```
n <- nrow(df)
df$start <- runif(n, max=df$Length)
df$end <- runif(n, min=df$start, max=df$Length)
```

Using the dplyr package:

```
df <- mutate(df, start=runif(n(), max=Length), end=runif(n(), min=start, max=Length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `df` to be your dataframe:

```
 df$random<-runif(nrow(df)) #just create a random column and fill it with random numbers
```

## apply the condition

```
 df$random<-ifelse(df$DefectEnds > df$DefectStarts,df$random,NA)#select rows with this condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode:

```
i for (1 to length(df){
  df[i,DefectStarts]=sample(df[i,Length],1,T)
  df[i,DefectEnds]=sample(df[i,Length]-df[i,DefectStarts],1,T)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick comments amonk and Ajay. Ajay's answer took only the first row into use and populated the entire table with only that condition, so it didnt work out. amonk's answer was a bit too roundabout way, as I have more than 10,000 lines of data

Comment: ok I changed it to make a loop to make sure it runs for that row only. Since I dont have R in office right now, it is pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

After some messing around with the code, this seemed to do the job :

Defect <- Defect[,DefectStarts:=runif(row_count,min=1,max=Defect$Length)]

Defect <-
 Defect[,DefectEnds:=runif(row_count,min=Defect$DefectStarts,max=Defect$Length)]

Thanks again for your support! Much appreciated. And please do suggest if there are any better ways to do this.